# Make BITWISE AND positive

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I was solving one problem and it stated that we need to find the sum of all minimum number that needs to be added to the elements in the array so that the bitwise AND is greater than 0.

For eg: Given array is **[4, 4, 3, 2]**

then the output should be **3**

(adding one to 1st 2nd and 4th element).

My approach : first I decided to find the position of the right most set in all elements and check for the overall minimum number to be added so that the and is greater than zero. But this is not working.Can anyone help in finding an alternative algo?

Comment: please tag only the lanugage relevant for the question. If none is relevant, because the question is about algorithms don't tag it

Comment: Is it allowed to add `1` to the 3d item, `2` to the 4th (`3` in total), and have `4 & 4 & 4 & 4 == 4`? Or we have to add *equal numbers* as `1` in the example?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko yes it is allowed. Even then also the result will be 3. (1 + 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's solve a bit different problem first:

> What minimum `min` number should be add to `value` to ensure `1` in `k`th position (zero based)?

We have two cases here:

if `value` has `1` at `k` position we add `0` (do nothing);

if `value` has `0` at `k` position we can add

```
   min = 100...000000000 - (value & 11.....11111)
          <- k zeroes ->            <- k ones ->
```

Code (C#)

```
  private static long AddToEnsureOne(long value, int position) {
    if ((value & (1L << position)) != 0)
      return 0;

    long shift = 1L << (position);

    return shift - (value & (shift - 1)); 
  }
```

Demo:  if we have `3` and we want `1` at 2nd position

```
   0b011
     ^
     we want 1 here
```

we should add

```
   0b100 - (0b011 & 0b11) == 4 - 3 == 1
```

let's add: `3 + 1 == 4 == 0b100` which has `1` at 2nd position

Now we can scan all 32 positions (if integer is good old 32 bit integer `int`); C# code:

```
  private static long MinToAdd(IEnumerable<int> items) {
    long best = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
      long sum = 0;

      foreach (int item in items)
        sum += AddToEnsureOne(unchecked((uint)item), i); // uint - get rid of sign

      if (i == 0 || sum < best)
        best = sum;
    }

    return best;
  }
```

One can improve the solution looping not for `32` positions but for the leftmost `1` of the maximum `item`. Here we have `4` as the maximum, which is `0b100`, the leftmost `1` is in the `2` position; thus `for (int i = 0; i <= 2; ++i)` will be enough in the context

Simple test:

```
  Console.Write(MinToAdd(new int[] { 4, 4, 3, 2}));
```

Outcome:

```
  3
```